# Unattended-upgrades can't update itself: SIGUSR1 received, will stop

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, update, unattended

We use "unattended-upgrades" on ubuntu xenial.
Since a few days "uu" can't update itself:

Manual run: `unattended-upgrades -d`
Message:

```
...pkg 'powermgmt-base' not in allowed origin...
```

My origins:

```
"${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-security";
"${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-updates";
```

**EDIT:**
I found the correct origin:

```
"${distro_id}:${distro_codename}";
```

Problem now is, that "UU" is unable to update itself:

```
Preparing to unpack .../unattended-upgrades_1.1ubuntu1.18.04.7~16.04.3_all.deb ...
SIGUSR1 received, will stop
SIGUSR1 received, will stop
SIGUSR1 received, will stop
SIGUSR1 received, will stop
```

Any advice?

Comment: Have a look in `/var/lib/apt/lists/*_InRelease` where `*` refers to the repository from where you get the `powermanagmt-base` package. Search for `Origin:` and add the origin given there to your configured origins.

Comment: Also have a look at my blog post here, your problem seems similar: https://blog.christosoft.de/2018/08/unattended-upgrades-mono-debian/

Comment: Thanks - I found the correct origin. Problem here is, that UU is unable to update itself: Preparing to unpack .../unattended-upgrades_1.1ubuntu1.18.04.7~16.04.3_all.deb ...
SIGUSR1 received, will stop
SIGUSR1 received, will stop
SIGUSR1 received, will stop

Comment: Hmmm. I am running unattended-upgrades both on Debian an Ubuntu for years and never had problems with it updating itself.... Of course, you could blacklist the package so it won't attempt update itself.

Comment: Please post your configuration of unattended upgrades. I will compare to mine.

Comment: Try changing `Unattended-Upgrade::MinimalSteps "true";`, try both true and false to see what works.

Comment: Thank you very much @ChristopherK. - Setting this option to "false" solved it!

Comment: Great. I posted the solution as an answer so other people finding this see the solution faster. Would be great if you could mark this answer as the solution to your problem.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, please vote it up and "accept" it. We will both get reputation. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`, change the following setting to **false**:

```
// Split the upgrade into the smallest possible chunks so that
// they can be interrupted with SIGUSR1. This makes the upgrade
// a bit slower but it has the benefit that shutdown while a upgrade
// is running is possible (with a small delay)
Unattended-Upgrade::MinimalSteps "true";
```

Answer (score 0):

This solved it for me:
Unattended-Upgrade::MinimalSteps "false";

This was "true" before!